# deleting objects in Core Data swift clearing up deletion issues

Tags: swift, core-data

Working in a part of code that I thought I had set correctly but it is yielding unwanted results. Lets say I have a core data store that is set up like so there is a Main, Secondary, Third, Fourth and Fifth. If I delete the main object then I want all relationships related to this object I set within this Entity Cascade for all relationships set under this entity correct?

Secondary is related to Main in a To-Many relationship and Main is set To-One in this relationship. Third is Related to Main in a To-Many Relationship and Main is set To-One. Second is related to Third in a To-One and Third is related back in a To-Many. Fourth is related to Main in a To-Many and Main is To-One. Fifth is never to be deleted and is related to Fourth in a To-One and Fourth is related back as To-Many. Now that's the setup.

Now lets say I deleted Main I want all objects related to this object deleted as well so I set all the relationships from inside this entity to Cascade? Deleting all relationships directly to this object entirely including the objects in fifth which are never to be deleted?

Also lets say I want to delete all objects in Third related to the Main object without actually deleting the main object I set the relationship to this one as and set it as nullify?

The issue I am having is that I am trying to delete all the objects related to Main if it is deleted except the Fifth Object as I don't want these objects touched ever, so I set the relationship to it as deny? 
Also when I try to delete the third objects I can delete them once but then when I try to do another clear of those same kind of objects it wont actually let me do it even if the main object is completely different. The code I am using to delete these objects is :

```
@IBAction func clearStats(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Clear?", message: "Do you wish to Clear the Info?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let deleteAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Stats", style: .Destructive) { (ACTION) -> Void in

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Third", inManagedObjectContext: self.context)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "counted = %@", self.deckRecord!)
    fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false
    do {
        if let results = try self.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {
            for result in results {
                self.context.deleteObject(result)
            }
            try self.context.save()
        }
        } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    }
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: A picture of the model is worth a thousand words... Also, show the save error returned.

Comment: solved the problem it was an issue with me parsing the wrong field....the delete is functioning fine now....I need to learn to stop panicking and asking without trying to solve my issues first....